# Error in AWS API Gateway: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a API (https public url) using API gateway and try to send a request using post method on that url and it is working on local machine but when i tried to send request on same url in production environment it gives 502 bad gateway as response, I have tried many options to figure out this issue but didn't able to resolve it. Please suggest a solution if any have any idea about this.

Comment: Where are you invoking your endpoint from? i.e., are you using a client-side script such as Javascript/jQuery or a server-side script such as PHP or .NET?

Comment: it is being called by  foursquare push api, which is showing 502 bad gateway as response and not getting any logs on aws

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more info about your production environment than "it doesn't work". My best guess so far is that your production code doesn't construct the request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

All API Gateway API endpoints are accessible from internet. If it works on your dev host and doesn't work on prod, then the issue is likely with your prod setup. Try doing a DNS lookup for the API url from prod host. If that doesn't resolve, you should solve that issue first.